# ogr.BuildPolygonFromEdges fails on my multiline

Tags: python, polygon, ogr

Using python ogr, `polygon = ogr.BuildPolygonFromEdges(multiline)` fails for the following multilinestring:

[image: Multiline]

Does anyone know why?

It throws the error: `RuntimeError: OGR Error: General Error` with exceptions enabled. Without exceptions:
`ERROR 6: OGR Error: General Error`

Edit: I think I should be using `polygon = multiline.Polygonize()` but this returns an empty geometry collection...

Edit2: The red line has 2 points, the green has 3. Do these need to be segmentized?

Edit3: Code that generated multiline:

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc4
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#ogr.UseExceptions()

ds_shp = None
drv_shp = None

# GoM
wkt_boundary = (
    'LINESTRING (-67.25 44.75 , -66. 44. , -66. 38. )',
    'LINESTRING (-71. 48. , -71. 38.)',
)
shapefile_boundary = (
    'topography/etopo1_GoMSS_0005m_edit.shp',
    'topography/etopo1_GoM_0200m.shp',
)

drv_mem = ogr.GetDriverByName('Memory')
ds_mem = drv_mem.CreateDataSource('source')
drv_shp = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

srs_in = None
multiline = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiLineString)
for shapefile_in in shapefile_boundary:
    ds_shp_in = drv_shp.Open(shapefile_in)
    layer_in = ds_shp_in.GetLayer()
    if srs_in is None:
        srs_in = layer_in.GetSpatialRef()
        layer_out = ds_mem.CreateLayer('GoM_lines', srs=srs_in, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
        layer_defn = layer_out.GetLayerDefn()
    for linestring_feature in layer_in:
        geometry_ref = linestring_feature.GetGeometryRef()
        multiline.AddGeometry(geometry_ref)

for wkt in wkt_boundary:
    linestring = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt, reference=srs_in)
    multiline.AddGeometry(linestring)
```

With:

```
print(multiline.GetGeometryName())
MULTILINESTRING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multiline is very difficult to polygonize. To show this I will use [Shapely's polygonize_full](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize_full) operation which merges MultiLineString or list of LineString into polygons and returns four geometry collections: polygons, dangles, cuts and invalid ring lines

The MultiLineString is composed of 4 LineString that intersects several times as in your example

[image]

```
from shapely.ops import polygonize
polygons, dangles, cuts, invalids = polygonize_full(mymultiline)
print(len(polygons), len(dangles),len(cuts),len(invalids))
(0, 0, 4, 0)
```

The polygons, dangles and invalids are empty, while the cuts contains the 4 original LineStrings (Cut edges are connected at both ends but do not form part of polygon)

> As with `ogr.BuildPolygonFromEdges(multiline)` and `multiline.Polygonize()` the polygons collection is empty

Now, I try with more lines to polygonize by splitting all the self-intersection geometries. I use the [Shapely unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) predicate

```
from shapely.ops import unary_union
t = unary_union(mymultiline)
mu = MultiLineString(t)
print(len(mu))
18
```

[image]

The MultiLineString is now composed of 18 LineString without self-intersections

```
polygons, dangles, cuts, invalids = polygonize_full(mu)
print(len(polygons), len(dangles),len(cuts),len(invalids))
(4, 1, 9, 0)
```

There are now 4 polygons, 1 dangle, 9 cuts and 0 invalids.

The polygons

[image]

The cuts

[image]

The dangles (Dangles are edges which have one or both ends which are not incident on another edge endpoint)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! With Shapely I made a union of my line segments into a multiline and then used shapely.ops.polygonize on the multiline. I also tried this with ogr, but could not polygonize the multiline.